# Loss files when publish new version apk in google play developer console

Tags: android

In my app I am store files in subdirectory of getExternalStorageDirectory (memory card). 
But when I am publish new version of apk in Google Play Developer Console some users write to me that they are losing files. why users lose their files? Maybe they remove sdcard? But if they have no sdcard?